# Connecting to a server via Java Socket and ServerSocket Class

Tags: java, security, tomcat, networking, server

I have what will hopefully be a very simple question. I'm writing a series of java programs which utilize cryptographic functions like RSA, El Gamal, etc for a security class. so that a client (Alice) and server (Bob) can communicate securely. But, I have no clue how to connect to a server on my computer using java. I've used MAMP to connect to a web server where I've written code in PHP/SQL, but I don't know how it would work using Java. Specifically, the starter files I was given all use the Java class Socket and ServerSocket like so:

```
String host = "localhost";
int port = 7999;
Socket s = new Socket(host, port);
ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
```

And for the server (Bob):

```
int port = 7999;
ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(port);
Socket client = s.accept();
ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());
```

What would I do on my computer to connect to a server via this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Client.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 7999;
        Socket s = new Socket(host, port);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        os.writeObject("Hello World");
        os.close();
    }

}
```

Server.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        int port = 7999;
        ServerSocket s = new ServerSocket(port);
        Socket client = s.accept();
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(client.getInputStream());

        String str = (String)is.readObject();

        System.out.println("Read string: " + str);

        is.close();
    }

}
```

Compile with

```
javac Client.java
```

and

```
javac Server.java
```

Run the server (you can test this running both on the same machine.)

```
java Server
```

Run the client (in another terminal or DOS prompt.)

```
java Client
```

On the server you should see:

```
server$ java Server 
Read string: Hello World
server$
```

Comment: Do i run a tomcat server on my machine while i do this?

Comment: This runs without Tomcat. These are two standalone java applications.

Comment: If you want to run in Tomcat (as a servlet?) that's a bit different. I can try to come up with an example but that will be somewhat more involved. In the mean time, you might try searching for something like: java Servlet using ObjectInputStream. 

The code you posted uses java sockets and object streams to send directly from a java client to a java server a java object. If you want to use a servlet you might need to look into the overhead of the HTTP protocol and what you need to get from the HttpServletRequest.

Comment: Nevermind. What you answered is exactly what i needed to do. Thanks!